# POST localhost/.. 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I was sending a request to a controller using Ajax but every time i got this errors:

these 2 errors when i refresh the page:

```
1) Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

2) Uncaught ReferenceError: Holder is not defined
```

and this error when i send request:

```
jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 POST localhost/.. 405 (Method Not Allowed)
send @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ 0:221
dispatch @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
y.handle @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
```

my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:
    {
        "_token":$("input[name=_token]").val(),
        'question_id':question_id,
        'user_id':user_id
    },
         href:"{{route('favorites.reds')}}",
         success: function (data) {
             console.log(data);
    }
})
```

the route:

```
Route::post('/questions/reds', "FavoritesController@addToReds")->name('favorites.reds');
```

Inputs:

```
 <i class="fa fa-heart" style="margin-right: 100px; cursor: pointer; " aria-hidden="true">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{$question->id}}" class="question_fav">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}" class="user_fav">
                    </i>
```

Can anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be using incorrect syntax in your `$.ajax` function.
Switch `href:"{{route('favorites.reds')}}"` to `url:"{{route('favorites.reds')}}` and see it that helps.

Comment: I did that and now i got this: POST localhost/..  419 (unknown status)

Comment: Can you confirm that the '_token' field is posting correctly - incorrect '_token' fields can sometimes cause 419 errors

Comment: I haven't post csrf anywhere. How should i do that?

Comment: try this: 
`$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:
    {
        "_token": '{{csrf_token()}}',
        'question_id':question_id,
        'user_id':user_id
    },
    url:"{{route('favorites.reds')}}",
    success: function (data) {
             console.log(data);
    }
})`

Comment: But the problem is not related to controller, everything is before controller

Comment: ok. any more info u can share on the 500 error? are you able to get more info from the 'response' in your inspect-tool console?

Comment: That was from the console. I Changed url to href and again got the 405 error

Comment: you should be getting a more detailed response in you console for the 500 error - check the 'response' tab in the console... https://www.google.com/search?biw=1680&bih=953&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=_uCCW8PZDe-k_Qar3ZO4Cw&q=chrome+inspect+server+response+gif&oq=chrome+inspect+server+response+gif&gs_l=img.3...50397.53539.0.53691.19.18.1.0.0.0.137.1065.17j1.18.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.0.0....0.ZftzbBelxi4#imgrc=63U2nDdi15o8EM: